# How do I show decimal calculations in python?

Tags: python, python-2.x

When I do a division in Python/Pandas (e.g. 47/100) how do I show the decimal value of the answer, because at the moment it just shows as 0?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Python 2 uses integer division such that type(int/int)=int.  This is a bug.  Cast one of the operands to a float.

Comment: @aestrivex: it is *not* a bug, the choice was deliberate. Python 3 made a different choice.

Comment: I consider it a bug.  I consider there to be a lot of bugs in the language specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using python2.x, you need to "floatify"<sup>1</sup> one of your numbers:

```
float(47)/100
47.0/100
```

As python2.x will do integer division if both numbers in the division are integers.

<sup><sup>1</sup>floatify: Forcing a number to be a float</sup>

Comment: Just another way: `operator.truediv(47, 100)` :)